# What can be worse than the punishment of Sodom and Gomorrah?

Tags: matthew, jude

Jude 1:7
New International Version

> In a similar way, Sodom and Gomorrah and the surrounding towns gave themselves up to sexual immorality and perversion. They serve as an example of those who suffer the punishment of **eternal fire**.

People of Sodom and Gomorrah will be burned in eternal fire.

Matthew 10:14

> If anyone will not welcome you or listen to your words, leave that home or town and shake the dust off your feet. 15 Truly I tell you, it will be **more bearable** for Sodom and Gomorrah on the day of judgment than for that town.

Isn't eternal fire the ultimate punishment? How can that town be punished even more severely?

Comment: The example (in time, on earth) was molten lava falling on people, which caused temporary pain and immediate death. Which is a warning about the future. Those who reject the gospel shall suffer the _reality_ of eternal fire which is far, far, far more than what the two cities suffered. This is perfectly clear. I cannot grasp what your question is expecting.

Comment: @NigelJ - except that Jude 7 is explicitly saying that Sodom and Gomorrah suffered the judgement of eternal fire.

Comment: @Dottard The original reads 'set forth as an example of fire eternal penalty undergoing' (EGNT). The 'example' is demonstrated on earth in time. What it is an example of is an eternal matter, not on this present earth.// προκεινται δειγμα πυρος αιωνιου δικην υπεχουσαι

Comment: @NigelJ - interesting interpretation that is not in the text to create a special pleading.

Comment: @Dottard Seems pretty clear that the temporal punishment of Sodom and Gommorrah is an example of the eternal fire that is to come. I can't see how Jude 7 could be read in any other way.

Comment: @curiousdannii - that just goes to show how much we are victims of our preconceptions.  There are many who do not read it that way, including great scholars.

Comment: @Dottard I think you're way overstating things to say Jude *explicitly* says S&G suffered the eternal fire. It's one interpretation but there are others.

Comment: @curiousdannii - that is simply what the text says.  Any other interpretation must twist the meaning by special pleadings that do not exist in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What can be worse than the punishment of Sodom and Gomorrah?

Certainly, there could not be a worse punishment. So it seems that Jesus was showing how bad the city of Capernaum was by using hyperbole.

The *Insight on the Scriptures* brings this out in the article about [Gomorrah](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=E&docid=1200001741&srctype=wol&srcid=share&par=6):

> When reproaching certain first-century Jewish cities, Jesus made reference to grossly wicked Sodom and Gomorrah. He directed such an expression of reproach to unrepentant Capernaum, where he personally had performed many of his powerful works. And regarding any city that would reject his disciples, failing to exercise faith in spite of the powerful works that they performed as evidence of divine backing, Jesus said: “It will be more endurable for the land of Sodom and Gomorrah on Judgment Day than for that city.” (Mt 10:5-15; 11:23, 24) Since Sodom and Gomorrah and the cities about them had been punished with “everlasting fire,” representing eternal annihilation, Jesus was evidently using a hyperbole in order to emphasize how unlikely it was that such faithless Jews would reform even if they were present on Judgment Day.—Jude 7.